# Check if one of formControl is dirty or changed

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanna check if one of formControlName of my formGroup is changed value. Since I have many formControl I want to find a smart way to control if one of this is changed.

```
<div>
    <label class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'questionario_codiceDomanda' | translate }}</label>

    <input formControlName="codDomanda" class="questionario-input-border form-control" type="text"
        (keyup)="changeCodDomanda($event)">
</div>
<!-- testo domanda -->
<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'questionario_testo' | translate }}</label>

    <textarea formControlName="testo" class="questionario-input-border form-control" type="text" rows="2" cols="90"
        (keyup)="changeTesto($event)"></textarea>
</div>
<!--help domanda-->
<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'questionario_help' | translate }}</label>
    <textarea formControlName="help" class="questionario-input-border form-control" type="text" rows="2"
        cols="90"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried with ngOnChanges but it doesn't work. What is the best way to check?

Comment: where do you want to check?

Comment: when someone change one of these input/textarea

Comment: and are you checking this for only some form controls or entire form controls inside form?

Comment: the entire form controls, my purpose is to show a popup at the end(when the user changed some form control) and when he wants to exit show the message that something is changed and if wants to save before to exit

Comment: the logic of popup is ok.. is on other function. But I wanna to "catch" when user changes something

Comment: you want to catch it to show or hide something or you have some other logic?

Comment: I have some other logic, I want just to know when on of my input/textare form is changed.. in this way I can use the other logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold">{{ 'questionario_help' | translate }}</label>
    <textarea formControlName="help" class="questionario-input-border form-control" type="text" rows="2"
        cols="90"></textarea>
</div>

<span class="help-block error-message" *ngIf="userDataForm.get('help').invalid && userDataForm.get('help').dirty">Error
    in Help</span>
```

Comment: this doesnt answer the op's problem

Comment: When the user clicks/touch on the textarea it will be dirty and if it is invalid you will have "Error in Help" message on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const formControlValueChanges = Object.keys(this.form.value).map((key) =>
        this.form.get(key).valueChanges.pipe(map((value) => ({ key, value })))
    );
    merge(...formControlValueChanges).pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    )
        .subscribe(({ key, value }) => { // Logic here }
```

Answer (score -1):

Subscribe to the form.valueChanges

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{
    //your logic when any one of form control is dirty
})
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-a5njgf

Comment: ok but there is a little problem.. if the user change something on input text and after delete the changes the dirty parameter remain still true